# I want awk the Numeric Value from the following context "Total Number of Records:35"

Tags: awk

I am beginner in shell scripting, Can anyone help me with below, 
I want awk the Numeric Value from the following context "Total Number of Records:35", it may also have space after Records, eg: "Total Number of Records: 35",

I was trying to use the below, but it's not working if the above context is having space

```
TNR=$(awk -F ':' '/^Total Number of Records/{print $NF}' f1.txt)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For your sample input, this simple `awk` program should be enough:

```
$ awk -F ': *' '{print $2}' file
```

It relies on the input field separator extended regular expression ([POSIX-compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html)): `: *` (colon followed by zero or more spaces), simply printing the second field after such a split.